# Query SQL - CASE com LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Preciso criar uma query que retorne todos os alunos ativos e suas notas para cada matéria. Caso o aluno não possua nota para determinada matéria deve ser retornado o aluno, a matéria e em nota o valor "Sem nota".

Creio que precisarei criar utilizando o CASE, mas ainda não estou certo disso. 
Bom, não estou conseguindo criar esta consulta. Podem me dar um help?

Abaixo segue a estrutura do banco (reduzida)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Aluno](
    [codigoAluno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [cpf] [decimal](15, 0) NOT NULL,
    [situacao] [bit] NOT NULL,
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Materia](
    [codigoMateria] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nome] [varchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [situacao] [bit] NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Nota](
    [codigoAluno] [int] NOT NULL,
    [codigoMateria] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sequencialMateria] [int] NOT NULL,
    [valor] [decimal](15, 2) NOT NULL,
)
```

Segue a query que eu consegui montar até agora.

```
SELECT 
    A.NOME,
    M.NOME, 
    CASE WHEN SUM(M.valor) > 0
             THEN SUM(M.valor)
             ELSE '0' -- Aqui ainda tem que mudar para 'Sem nota'
        END AS 'NOTA'
FROM MATERIA M
LEFT JOIN NOTA N ON M.codigoMateria = N.codigoMateria
LEFT JOIN ALUNO A ON A.codigoALUNO = N.codigoALUNO
--WHERE F.situacao = 1
GROUP BY A.NOME, M.nome, N.valor
ORDER BY A.NOME, M.NOME
```

Nesta query, está faltando apenas acrescentar a matéria cujo aluno não tenha nota lançada.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx   pesquise por outer join

Comment: Experimenta trocar a linha `CASE WHEN SUM(M.valor) > 0` por `CASE WHEN SUM(M.valor) IS NOT NULL`, vê se resolve.

Comment: PedroMVM não funciona por quê não chega a exibir a matéria cujo aluno não tenha nota lançada.

Comment: @BrunoHeringer: Todo aluno deve fazer todas as matérias que constam na tabela MATERIA? // O que é a coluna sequencialMateria? // É para listar cada matéria como coluna? O que significa a coluna `situacao`, da tabela `MATERIA`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neste caso o ideal seria usar um `CROSS JOIN` com `subquery`:

```
SELECT alu.nome AS aluno,
       mat.nome AS materia,
       ISNULL((SELECT CAST(AVG(not.valor) AS VARCHAR)
                 FROM nota not
                WHERE not.codigoMateria = mat.codigoMateria
                  AND not.codigoAluno = alu.codigoAluno), 'SEM NOTA') AS media 
  FROM materia mat
       CROSS JOIN aluno alu
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Explicando a `query`:

- O `CROSS JOIN` combina todos os registros da tabela `materia` com os registros da tabela `aluno` afinal precisamos de uma linha pra cada aluno em cada matéria;
- A `subquery` na tabela `nota` resultado na média (`AVG`) das notas lançadas para aquela matéria e aquele aluno em questão;
- O `ISNULL` permite que a informação `SEM NOTA` apareça caso nenhum registro na tabela `nota` seja encontrado (Resultando em `NULL`);
- Utilizamos o `CAST(... AS VARCHAR)` para que não ocorra um erro ao juntar as informações de nota com algum possível registro que retorne `SEM NOTA`;

Answer (score 2):

Eis sugestão para avaliar:

```
-- código #1 v2
with cteAcumNotas as (
SELECT A.codigoAluno, A.nome as nomeAluno,
       M.codigoMateria, M.nome as nomeMateria,
       sum(N.valor) as valor
  from ALUNO as A
       cross join MATERIA as M
       left join NOTA as N on N.codigoAluno = A.codigoAluno 
                              and N.codigoMateria = M.codigoMateria
  where A.situacao = 1
  group by A.codigoAluno, A.nome, M.codigoMateria, M.nome
)
SELECT codigoAluno, nomeAluno, nomeMateria,
       coalesce(cast(valor as varchar(20)), 'sem nota') as somaNotas
  from cteAcumNotas
  order by nomeAluno, codigoAluno, nomeMateria;
```

As colunas codigoAluno e codigoMateria foram utilizadas por causa de possíveis homônimos.